# Open mp3 files in android default media player on the same activity

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an Android application in which I am showing a `ListView` of mp3 files from the sd card.

Now what I want is that when user clicks on any of the mp3 files it should start playing there on the same `Activity`. The code which I am using presently is not working for me to play audio files.

My code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/music/sample.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

**But this is something that I want. This is a screen Shot form android gingerbread**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "default media player"? I only now [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) MediaPlayer.

Comment: @MalaKa means which is provided by android only

Comment: I didn't know that player.. but have a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/1kUO79BngyQ). There is some code in the post of "Peli" that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should use another approach in case you want audio played in the same activity. I'd better initialize `MediaPlayer` object in this activity or as a `background service`.

In case of any questions feel free to ask.

**UPDATE 1**

In general case as I said you either need the `MediaPlayer` object in Activity or `Music Service`.

Now lets talk about controls.

You can simply put into your layout the block with controls and show/hide it when needed. MediaPlayer provides several convenient callbacks, so you will be able to update progressbar.

So, sum up:

1. Include controls into layout.
2. Include MediaPlayer into activity or make it work as a Service.
3. Bond controls to player.
4. ???
5. PROFIT

Comment: @Er.NikhilAgrawal, yup, I reviewed it.

Answer (score 3):

see this link here is a good example of getting all the music files and show in list and play when you click any item...

1. [Display MusicList and play on itemClick](http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html)
2. [Another link](http://z4android.blogspot.in/2011/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html)

Comment: But it is running music in background But I want to have controls also

Comment: what you actully want to do...??

Comment: Wait I am taking screen shot